# box-shadow appearing below form

Tags: forms, overflow, css-position, css

I have a responsive fluid layout, dividing the page into two sections top and bottom by 50% height each, with 100% height parent. Top part is a wrapper for an image with box shadow css applied and the below section is a content div with `overflow:auto`.

The issue i'm having is if there is a form inside the below content div, and when scrolled the form appears above the shadow. I'm not sure if i have explained this correctly. But i have made a demo fiddle for demo purposes - [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/SknBw/26/)

I have no idea why this would be happening. Have I missed something? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `position: relative;` to `.weirdbox`

See [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/SknBw/30/) for working example.

The z-index property works only on absolute or relative positioned elements.

Comment: Perfect, your a legend! Thanks